# unable to place javascript into if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this nifty little if else statement prepared for i.e9 being a zombie browser that doesn't support things like css3 animations (generally)  this is the if statement ....

```
if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
    ms_ie = true;
}
if (ms_ie) {

} else {

}
$('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(3000, 1);
```

I am trying to fit this script into the if else statement...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mission,#overview,#music,#potential,#people,#expression,#ethos,#cpd,#workshop,#team,#referrals,#local-links,#family,#mental,#palliative,#autism,#schools,#dementia,#private,#acreditations,#definitions,#research,#contact,#email,#phone,#contact-form,#finley,#councelling,#music-performance,#community-music,.slides").addClass("bounceOutUp");
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log($("#tam-content").load($(that).data("url") + ' ' + $(that).data("target")));
            $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

so that it looks like this ....

```
if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
    ms_ie = true;
}
if (ms_ie) {    
    $("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log($("#tam-content").load($(that).data("url") + ' ' + $(that).data("target")));
            $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
        }, 1000);
    });
} else {
    $("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mission,#overview,#music,#potential,#people,#expression,#ethos,#cpd,#workshop,#team,#referrals,#local-links,#family,#mental,#palliative,#autism,#schools,#dementia,#private,#acreditations,#definitions,#research,#contact,#email,#phone,#contact-form,#finley,#councelling,#music-performance,#community-music,.slides").addClass("bounceOutUp");
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log($("#tam-content").load($(that).data("url") + ' ' + $(that).data("target")));
            $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
        }, 1000);
    });
```

But for some reason it doesn't work.. I took out the document.ready bit and i don't think that is the problem but unsure.. Can someone help ?

Comment: What does not work? Getting any errors? Oh and browser checks in client-side is not reliable.

Comment: it is being tested on a web server and when you click on the button it just does nothing . no errors but haven't debugged and don't trust my syntax

Comment: check whether userAgent condition is working fine?. any errors??

Comment: ok. I suggest divide and conquer your problem with the most basic piece of script you can write. First, check if the browserchecks are working with logging to console. Next check if the request gets send and log the result to console.. if both work great glue them together...

Comment: yeah i am in debug now but it isn't showing anything ... in theory chopping the code into two bits should work right ?

Comment: Yes, chopping down is a great way to debug your code. Setting breakpoints will help even more!

Comment: im using a remote desktop to a i.e9 machine to test on that so i only go so far before the connection breaks :0)

Comment: from a syntax point of view it is right though ?

Comment: I'm not a parser but when I format the code in a bit I will take a look at it ;)

Comment: thank you very much , working on it now

Comment: There is a missing bracket but I guess that's from copy & pasting. The syntax looks fine.

Comment: YES and the other closing braces needed to be inside the if and else parts ... posting the answer now

Answer (score 0):

HOOORAY !!

So basically this is the solution, the closing braces needed to be inside the if and else parts that are now split naturally....

```
if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
        ms_ie = true;
      }
      if ( ms_ie ) {
        $("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($("#tam-content").load($(that).data("url") + ' ' + $(that).data("target")));
        $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
        }, 1000);
        });
     }else{
        $("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mission,#overview,#music,#potential,#people,#expression,#ethos,#cpd,#workshop,#team,#referrals,#local-links,#family,#mental,#palliative,#autism,#schools,#dementia,#private,#acreditations,#definitions,#research,#contact,#email,#phone,#contact-form,#finley,#councelling,#music-performance,#community-music,.slides").addClass("bounceOutUp");
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
       console.log($("#tam-content").load($(that).data("url") + ' ' + $(that).data("target")));
       $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
        }, 1000);
        });
      }
```

This is a great little method of running browser specific code, you should check it out!